# Is it necessary to use the "in" modifier with a readonly struct?

Tags: c#

In C# 7.2, are readonly structs always passed to functions as if the "in" parameter is present? If not, in what case would it be useful to copy the memory given that it's readonly?

I have a readonly struct:

```
public readonly struct Vec2 
{
     public readonly double X;
     public readonly double Y;
}
```

So would there be a performance difference between these two methods when called billions of times:

```
public double Magnitude1(Vec2 v)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y);
}
public double Magnitude2(in Vec2 v)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y);
}
```

And if so, why doesn't the compiler recognize that Vec2 is a readonly struct and just pass it as if "in" were present? Is there an instance where you might want to pass a readonly struct without the "in" modifier?

Comment: `And if so, why doesn't the compiler recognize that Vec2 is a readonly struct and just pass it as if "in" were present?` https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/

Comment: `So would there be a performance difference between these two methods when called billions of times:` https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @mjwills Fixed. Also the whole point of the "in" modifier is performance, so of course I'm asking about performance. Also I am not asking why C# doesn't have a particular feature - I am asking if there is any application where the "in" keyword would NOT be the best thing to do.

Comment: Trying to figure out if I should be spamming the "in" modifier all over my Vec2/Vec3 classes or not...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are readonly structs always passed to functions as if the "in" parameter is present?

No. Without the `in` modifier, `readonly` structs are passed by value, not by reference.

> If not, in what case would it be useful to copy the memory given that it's readonly?

It would be useful to copy the memory if you wanted to guarantee the memory didn't change. Keep in mind that a struct can be changed even if it's `readonly`. For example:

```
readonly struct S
{
    public readonly int I;

    public S(int i) { this.I = i; }
}

class Program
{
    static S s1 = new S(1);

    static void Main()
    {
        A(s1);
    }

    static void A(in S s2)
    {
        Console.Write(s2.I);
        s1 = new S(2); // This is legal even though S is readonly!
        Console.Write(s2.I);
    }
}
```

With the `in` modifier on parameter `s2`, the output is 12. Without the `in` modifier, the output is 11.

This difference in behavior means the compiler cannot transparently add `in` modifiers to `readonly struct` parameters. (Even if method `A` didn't modify `s1`, another thread could.)

> So would there be a performance difference between these two methods when called billions of times?

There might be; measure it and see. I'd expect that the larger the struct, the slower it would be to pass by value.

> And if so, why doesn't the compiler recognize that Vec2 is a readonly struct and just pass it as if "in" were present? Is there an instance where you might want to pass a readonly struct without the "in" modifier?

Maybe if the `struct` were very small (say, 8 bytes or less), passing by value (e.g., in a CPU register) could be cheaper than passing by reference (and then having to dereference the pointer).

Comment: I think the comment "*This is legal even though S is readonly!*" is a bit misleading. Would you be happy for it to be "*This is legal because it's assigning a new instance of `S` to the field, and not modifying the instance of `S`* in the field"?

Comment: @WaiHaLee: `S` is a struct, so there is no difference between "assigning a new instance of `S` to the field" and "modifying the instance of `S` in the field". Make sure you understand this: if you have a mutable `struct A { public int N; public A(int n) { this.N = n; } }` and a mutable field `A a`, then `a = new A(1)` and `a.N = 1` have *exactly the same effect*. (In contrast, if `A` were a class, then those two statements would do different things.) My comment emphasizes the non-intuitive fact that even though `S` is `readonly`, the *existing* instance of `S` in the `s1` field is changed.

Comment: I see - so you're saying that because you're replacing the whole instance, it's effectively the same as changing a field in the instance of the struct. Then when you call the method without using `in` it creates a copy (pass by value) so the modification of the field `Program.s1` has no effect because a different instance of the struct is passed into the method - hence the output of `11`. And when you *do* have `in`, there is no defensive copy (pass by reference) so modifying the value of the field `Program.s1` the same instance is passed into the method, hence the output of `12`.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: Correct!